# Should I delete my own question if no new answer can be validated?

Tags: discussion, questions

A while ago, I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/356321/windows-7-host-does-not-answer-to-ping) for which no solution was found. I have since re-installed the host in question and gave it to a family member.
So now I will be unable to validate any answers given (if there might be new ones) and the problem was never solved either.

So, should I delete that question?

The reason I am especially torn about this question is that I put some research effort into it which someone else might profit from if he/she experiences the same issue. Then again I don't like to have questions open for which I could never determine a definitive solution.

---

I voted to close the question. I think the key is that no answer can be validated. Whatever additional information I (or someone else) might have gathered, it isn't even sure if it would have lead towards a solution to the initial issue. So none of the content in the original question is of real value either.

Comment: Great question. I have always wondered about troubleshooting questions where the users simply give up and wipe the system.

Comment: I think a troubleshooting question that cannot be validated would fall under the "too localised" category

Comment: @Paul Depends also on how many answers there are. Some problems are more common than others. Even if the OP is no longer interested, others might be.

Comment: Regarding the edit, are you specifically asking only about your question? If not, we should try to establish a general guideline that can also help other users to decide how to vote and/or flag when the OP has abandoned the question.

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm looking for a general guideline. Hopefully I will be able to apply it to my specific question. I just wanted to clarify why I'm having such a hard time deciding on my own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I don't see any point being on system, especially if there's no way to validate if an answer is right or wrong. You could argue it *may* help others, but in my experience, it usually ends up with I-haz-this-too "answers", which are pointless.

I'd probably Flag/Vote To Close as off-topic with custom off-topic message being

> Can no longer verify answers

I tend to go through old too localized/abandoned questions with no solutions and very low views & delete them as part of regular pruning exercise, this would probably get wiped as part of that.

So, yes it would make sense to delete the question, or at least VTC/Flag it for deletion

Comment: Considering "too localized" is no longer an option, perhaps this answer should be updated. (closing as "other" isn't ideal, since it falls under "off-topic"... I believe that carries a -1 penalty?)

Comment: @Bob updated...