# What to do with questions that can't be solved.....except by re-install?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Taking a look at this question:

> [Problems with sound and flash in Ubuntu 12](https://superuser.com/q/431136/47225)

The OP asks a questions and then answers it with "Oh! Fixed it by re-installing linux!"  I've noticed as I've browsed before, where this has happened (although I can't seem to be able to find them ATM).  My question is, what do we do with question/answer pairs that contain no real content for the rest of the community?  In other words, if the sole answer to a question is from the OP && contains "Fixed it by re-installing `[insert OS/Program here]`" should we keep them here on SU?

Comment: Found another one tonight: https://superuser.com/questions/858290/adding-a-switch-hangs-my-network (OP said cable was faulty, I tried to generalize the answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In such cases, I would instantly close as *Too localized*.

I asked a similar question (I believe) about how to deal with your own questions in such a case:
[Should I delete my own question if no new answer can be validated?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4192/should-i-delete-my-own-question-if-no-new-answer-can-be-validated)

I feel like the answer could be helpful.

Comment: I was typing an almost same answer, minus the link

Comment: That first line was my idea. Idea stolen so -1.

Comment: Then why am I still the only one who put his close vote in on that question? :D

Comment: No, not only you. May be your browser is working properly. ;p

Comment: It's not like "fixed it by reinstall" doesn't provide any info. Personally when I'm searching online for a solution and I find someone with the same problem, if reinstall is the only solution I can find then I will at least know that works. If I can't find any other solution on the web then I will assume that reinstall is the only option. If it truly is the only solution then the BEST answer you could give would be something like "Reinstall. It's you're only option."