# impact of wrongly answered questions on percentage accepted

Tags: support

For example:

[ddd+ubuntu+gnuplot error](https://superuser.com/questions/213360/dddubuntugnuplot-error)

the answer by RedGrittyBrick, while correct is not very relevant to the problem.

accepting it would not really make sense, and not accepting it impacts the "Percentage answered" stat.

What is the advised course of action in such cases?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4192/should-i-delete-my-own-question-if-no-new-answer-can-be-validated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want a better answer, you or somebody should place a bounty on your question. You can also politely nudge the answerers to improve their answers. Other than that, it's perfectly okay for a question to remain without an acceptable answer.