# What to do if you posted a question, but you can no longer test a provided solution?

Tags: support, questions

I posted [this](https://superuser.com/questions/728116/excel-2013-error-when-launching-excel-files) question 5 months ago.  No one provided an answer and I didnt solve the issue on my own.  Since posting it, I had long since forgotten I even asked the question.

Today, someone provided an answer.  Unfortunately, it was a very low quality answer, that provided no help so I flagged it.

The real issue is that I no longer work at that company, nor does the person who had the error.  So there is no way to test a real solution if one was provided.

Should I make a comment stating this?  Just let it be?  Whats the best practice in this solution?

Comment: You could, in theory, ask to have it deleted or closed. The *next* guy can ask the same question, and you have no real way of making sure the answer works anyway

Comment: Related: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4192/should-i-delete-my-own-question-if-no-new-answer-can-be-validated